# How do i do a request to a third party api? using httpclient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Currently, I need to integrate the CoinGecko API, this is a free API open to the public. (https://www.coingecko.com/api/docs/v3)

The HTTP client sends the request but it never returns a response

```
string BaseUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3";

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/coins/list");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.Coins>>(data);
            }
```

The expected result is that it should return the coins list, but it never does.

Comment: I went on the URL you have given, some people already developed a .net client for this api, why don't you just use it ? https://github.com/tosunthex/CoinGecko

Comment: @B.Lec your suggestion was the solution i did not see there was a api

Answer (score 0):

Change BaseUrl to:

```
 string BaseUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com";
```

and the GetAsync call to

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/v3/coins/list");
```